# Inspect messages to metamask

Tags: metamask, web3.py

There is a new crosschain dap meson.to that I am using.  The dap allows for cross chain stable transfers by signing a message in metamask.  I am wanting to use meson in web3.py.

I am familiar with inspecting API calls in chrome but have no idea how to inspect calls to metamask.  I am assuming that the local Js code will generate the message and send it to metamask for signing then the signed message would be sent to an API.  Therefore I need to reproduce both of these stages.

I have tried to inspect the Json code but am not familiar with how the metamask Js interface works so have come up short.

Can someone confirm that my understanding is correct and point me in the right direction.

Fyi once I have the message and know where to send it I should have no problem with the signing in web3.py